# Executing a function when the console window closes?

Tags: python

I want to execute a function when the program is closed by user.

For example, if the main program is `time.sleep(1000)`,how can I write a txt to record unexpected termination of the program.

The program is packaged into exe by cxfreeze. Click the "X" to close the console window.

I know [atexit](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/atexit.html) can deal with sys.exit(),but is there a more powerful way can deal with close window event?

**Questions**

1. Is this possible in Python?
2. If so, how can I do this?

Comment: Could you be a little more specific? Which OS, which program, which function?

Comment: and how does the user close the program?? Is it GUI?? Please be more specific....

Comment: @Schorsch Sorry for my poor expression.

Comment: No need to be sorry. Just keep improving your question, by being as precise as possible (look at the questions that are posted in comments here).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest you will get is using an exit handler:

```
def bye():
  print 'goodbye world!!'

import atexit
atexit.register(bye)
```

This may not work depending on technical details of how python is terminated (it relies on normal interpreter termination)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`atexit` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/atexit.html) to register functions to be executed when the program exits.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to wrap your behavior in a try/finally, with your exit behavior in the finally block.

```
try:
  normal_behavior()
finally:
  on_exit_behavior()
```